# Failing to implement service reference: Custom tool warning

Tags: c#, wcf

i have created a wcf service using .net 4.5 and implementing it worked just fine at the first.

At some reason i removed the service from my project and then added it again. When i added it this time i got Custom tool warnings.

*I have tryed to create a new project and implemented the service there **without any problem.**
All the Service contracts were added.*

The things who fails in my default project is the following:

1. Fails to create code in web.config
2. Fails to created service contracts **but** all datacontracts is added.

**Warnings displaying:**

```
    Warning 16  Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: ISerializable type with data contract name 'FileInfo' in namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.IO' cannot be imported. The data contract namespace cannot be customized for ISerializable types and the generated namespace 'itsperfect.Extreme.Web.Booking.MailClient' does not match the required CLR namespace 'System.IO'. Check if the required namespace has been mapped to a different data contract namespace and consider mapping it explicitly using the namespaces collection. 
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:portType[@name='IMailService']   C:\Dev\TFS\Booking\Main\src\Web.Booking\Service References\MailClient\Reference.svcmap  1   1   Web.Booking


    Warning 17  Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:portType[@name='IMailService']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:binding[@name='BasicHttpBinding_IMailService']   C:\Dev\TFS\Booking\Main\src\Booking\Service References\MailClient\Reference.svcmap  1   1   Web.Booking


    Warning 18  Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:binding[@name='BasicHttpBinding_IMailService']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:service[@name='MailService']/wsdl:port[@name='BasicHttpBinding_IMailService']    C:\Dev\TFS\Booking\Main\src\Web.Booking\Service References\MailClient\Reference.svcmap  1   1   Web.Booking
```

**Things i have tried:**

1. Deleted service reference & added again.
2. Removed "Reuse types in reference", restarted.
3. Cleaned project after delete of service, then added again.

Answer (score 1):

Found the error! Kendo.Mvc.dll was the assembly causing the problem, removed it as a reference and added it again.

Comment: I know it's been a few years but do you remember how you decided on this assembly in particular?

Comment: Ignore me, I am a dope. I deleted the assembly someone had built and copy/pasted into my solution in favor of adding the project to the solution and adding a solution reference to that project from my first project.